# window.open works; window.opener get's cleared on the child if I refresh the child

Tags: javascript, window.opener

So I have a button that calls a javascript window.open.
Fine, the child window opens, but it is a long list and I would like have a Search functionality on this child and makes a roundtrip to the server and returns whatever rows contain the search phrase. 
Without searching, it all works and send back the selected row to the window.opener inputs.
With searching, my roudntrip to the server/database clears the window.opener value.

Any ideas of how to get around this and be able to search plus return values to the window.opener?
I have searched for the last hour and it seems all the things I've found are about refreshing the parent from the child.

Comment: Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to perform the search without refreshing the page. It's a pretty common thing.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Problem is I need to return a whole dataset with same sized rows, only less rows. Not sure how to do that with Razor Pages because I am just looping thru building rows out of an array more or less.

Comment: Herohtar, please make your comment an answer and I will accept it. It pointed me in the right direction